# Does the XML Report Processing work for NUnit3?

Tags: nunit, teamcity-9.0

I'm currently moving one of our projects to DNX (.NET Core now) and I was forced to update to nunit3. Because of other considerations, we run compile the test project as a console app with its own entry point, basically self-hosting the NUnit runner.

I now need to report the results to TeamCity via the XML Reporter, which doesn't seem to parse Nunit3 TestResults.xml files.

Any advice on how to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to the answer above:
NUnitLite inherits the --result CLI parameter which seems to do the trick.

Another option, which I went for in the end is using the --teamcity CLI parameter:

`dotnetbuild --project:&lt;path to project directory&gt; -- --teamcity`

which will integrate with TC's service messages. This will also do real-time updates.

Answer (score 1):

The NUnit 3 console has the option to produce results formatted in the NUnit 2 style.

Use the option:

```
--result=[filename];format=nunit2
```

Docs: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Console-Command-Line